# How to get a variable value from aspx(jquery) to its codebehind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery variable like

```
Default.aspx:
  $(function () {
    $("#divimgbtnGo").click(function () {

       var ServiceNo = $(".ddlService option:selected").val();

    });
});
```

Here I am getting value into ServiceNo. I want to use these value in my codebehind (Default.aspx.cs).

Can anyone please help?

All information in search is about getting codebehind to aspx. SO could not found any useful result and stuck here

Comment: The drop down list box is send their selection to code behind with out do anything else. Now if you with so manipulate the `serviceNo` value and send it on code behind, you need to add it to some other hidden input control.

Comment: @Aristos SO never mentioned that ddlService  is a server side control ..

Comment: @rahularyansharma Did not matter if its server side control, its looks that is a drop down list, so its send their selection to code behind anyway.

Comment: without runat="server" how you find value in c# ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma Using the `Request.Form` - check it out.

Comment: Actully $(".ddlService option:selected").val(); is in my Parent page.., i want my parent page controls value in my Child Table Code Behind

Comment: @Pink With that you say now, you totally change your question. And the child window is with iframe on the parent ? What is the Parent/ Child on your case ?

Answer (score 1):

Have  a hidden feild in your aspx page then pass your variable value to that hidden field like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#divimgbtnGo").click(function () {
        $("#<%= yourhiddenfield.ClientID %>").val($(".ddlService option:selected").val());
    });
});
```

In your Code behind get the value of hidden field as yourhiddenfield.Value

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, a [Hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx), so `ASP.NET` will take care of transfering that data to the server and mapping it to `CLR` datatype after.

Comment: SO again do i need to assign these variable value to hidden filed and transer ??

Comment: @Pink: sure, you need to set the value into the field, so when the field is trasmited the valie of it can be read.

Answer (score 0):

You can take hidden field and set ServiceNo value to hiddenField and u can use hiddenfield in server side.
add hidden field in Default.aspx page
`<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnServiceNo" runat="server" />`

set hidden field value.

```
$(function () {
$("#divimgbtnGo").click(function () {

   var ServiceNo = $(".ddlService option:selected").val();
   $('#hdnServiceNo').val(ServiceNo );
});
```

});